# How do i get list instead of list of list?

Tags: python, list, readfile

I am trying to read a text file with the following format `"a b c d e f g h"`. I take a new empty list `word = []`

My code is:

```
f = open("letters.txt")

word = []

for line in f:
    line = line.split(" ")
    word.append(line)
print(word)
```

However, it has given me a list of list like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

But I want to get it in a single list instead?

eg:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: @RahulKP ^Nope, only words of the first line.

Comment: You might want to clarify the somewhat confusing terminology in your question.  `['a', 'b', 'c']` suggests you want a list of characters, while I am pretty sure you want a list of *words*. Also *word* (instead of word**s**) as a list is confusing for the same reason.

Comment: Hi PRnoob, please clarify ^. The question is unclear as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
word = open("letters.txt").read().split()
```

**Result**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Not very nice on huge files :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm OP described about the small content. That's why i suggest this solution.

Comment: He mentions the *format*, I don't see anything on the size. On smaller files, I'd do it your way though. I believe he means something else than he describes though on the format...

Answer (score 0):

You can print your line instead.

```
f = open("letters.txt")

for line in f:
    line = line.split(" ")
print line
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul's answer is correct. But this should help you understands when not to use `append`

`append(x)` adds x as a new element on the end of the list. It doesn't matter what x is `extend` would have worked.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(1)
>>> l.append('a')
>>> l.append({1,2,3})
>>> l.append([1,2,3])
>>> l
[1, 'a', set([1, 2, 3]), [1, 2, 3]]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> l.extend([1])
>>> l.extend([4,5,6])
>>> l
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know what data is in each variable in each line of the code. If you don't know - print it and then you will know.

I'll do it for you this time ;)

```
f = open("letters.txt")
# f is an open file object. BTW, you never close it.
# Consider: with open("letters.txt", "rt") as f:

word = []
# 'word' is a list. That is strange, why not 'words = []'?

for line in f:
    # 'line' is a string. Fine.

    line = line.split(" ")

    # 'line' is no longer a string. Not fine.
    # This is perfectly valid code, but bad practice.
    # Don't change the type of data stored in a variable,
    # or you'll run into problems understanding what your code does.
    # Make a new variable, if you need one, e.g. 'line_words'.

    # Anyway, 'line' is now a list of words. Whatever.

    word.append(line)

    # This added a list (line) into another list (word).
    # Now it is a list of lists. There is your error.
    # 'word += line' would do what you wanted.
```

All together:

```
with open("letters.txt", "rt") as f:
    words = []
    for line in f:
        words += line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this after getting your current result:

```
import itertools
a = [["a","b"], ["c"]]
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

This list is appended *as a whole* at the end of `word`. This is why you get a list of lists

```
word [
    [ result of split of first line ]
    [ result of split of second line ]
    [ result of split of third line ]
    [ ... ]
]
```

If you want to add each element of the list, instead of appending the list as a whole, you may use [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), i.e.

```
for line in f:
    a = line.split(" ")
    word.extend(a)
```

Although you might want to strip the trailing newline with [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip), when reading multiple lines

```
a = line.rstrip().split(" ")
```

or just use `None` as word separator

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

```
a = line.split()
```